# How do you find inverse of mod with large exponents?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Something like

$2^{125} \pmod {127}$

Would you apply the Extend Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: Since 127 is prime, this means $a^{126} \equiv 1 \mod 127$ for any $a\not\equiv 0 \mod 127$ by Fermat's little theorem. Hence $2^{125} \cdot 2 \equiv 1 \mod 127$. Thus $2^{125}$ has an inverse, and this inverse is $2$.

Comment: Is the inverse just what's left over? So like 
3^125 * 3 would have an inverse of 3?

Comment: The inverse of a quantity $a$ ($\mod n$) is the unique number $a^{-1}$ such that $a \cdot a^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$. An inverse only exists if and only if $gcd(a,n) = 1$.

Comment: In your example $3^{125}$ would have $3$ as its inverse.

Comment: No sweat :) Be sure to remember Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: What do you wish to invert, $\,2,\,$ or $\,2^{135}?\ \ $